# Create virtual environment with all packages shown in `conda list`

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

## Problem

I am trying to create a virtual environment for my deep learning project. However, after I created and activated the environment called `venv` using the following commands

```sh
conda create -n venv anaconda
conda activate venv
```

I found that many of the deep learning packages were **not** shipped with this virtual environment (the left panel is `conda list` outside the virtual env while the right panel is the one inside).

I noticed that packages not imported has "channel" property called `conda-forge` or `pytorch`

Therefore, I am wondering how could I create an virtual environment that copies **all** packages rather than that only have native packages. Thank you in advance!
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why dont you export the results of conda list into a text file, then make a new venv using this text file:

```
conda list --export > requirements.txt
conda create -n new --file requirements.txt
```

I think you can also do this, but haven't tested:

```
conda create -n new --clone base
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I tested the second option, it works!

Comment: I'm fairly certain that the issue is the create command. The OP ommited the `python=X.X` pararmeter. I.e. the create command should be `conda create -n venv python=3.7 anaconda`.